# Exclude rows from data.frame depending on a subset of the data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following simulated data.frame:

(please note that I have re-written large portions of the question, reflecting akrun's answer to my initial question)

```
set.seed(22)
df <- data.frame(f1 = rep("a", 20), f2 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no", "maybe", "maybenot"), 20, replace = T)), f3 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = T)), f4 = factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), 20, replace = T)))

   f1       f2  f3  f4
1   a    maybe yes yes
2   a       no yes yes
3   a      yes  no  no
4   a    maybe yes  no
5   a    maybe  no yes
6   a maybenot  no yes
...
```

I would like to exclude all rows that do **not** show a `yes` in `df$f2`, and show a `no`in either `df$f3`, or `df$f4`. If I would manually transform the values into 0s and 1 (0 for everything except `yes`in `df$f2`), I could use `rowSums` as suggested by akrun. My current solution is to introduce a dummy column called `df$exclude` as follows and then to `subset` on `df$exclude`:

```
df$exclude <- "no"
df[df$f2 != "yes" | df$f3 == "no" | df$f4 == "no",]$exclude <- "yes"    
df <- subset(df, exclude == "no")
```

Can't this be accomplished more concisely, e.g. without a prior transformation of the columns f2, f3, and f3, or by using `lapply` (somehow combined with `subset`, and possibly an anonymous function)?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I am not sure how your edit served the purpose.

Comment: Your description and code seems to be conflicting.  Do you need `df[!rowSums(df[2:4] != "yes"),]`  It is better to use `set.seed` for making reproducible example and expected output based on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to `exclude` rows that have 0 values for 'f2', 'f3' and 'f4', just do a `rowSums` to create a logical `vector` and `subset` the dataset

```
subset(df, rowSums(df[2:4]!=0) != 0)
```

#### Update

Based on the update in the OP's post

```
df[!rowSums(df[2:4] != "yes"),]
```

Comment: I have used 0 and 1 here for expository purposes, the real data.frame would contain text strings like `na`, `no`, `yes` etc. This solution would work if I would transform the text strings in 0s and 1s, accordingly.

Comment: @T.Kiss  I have used this solution only for expository purposes.  You can extend it to the real data.  When somebody post a question with a reproducible example, we expect it to be replica of the real data.

Comment: Sorry for not adding `set.seed()`, and thanks for your answer.